# Which DLL(s) must I ship alongside my EXE to use the Windows 10 Universal CRT?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, deployment, windows-10

I have used Visual Studio 2015 to compile a C program into a 32-bit EXE that dynamically links to the CRT. I want to allow users to download and run this EXE without the need to run a `VCRedist` binary first. It therefore seems I need to deploy some DLLs "app-locally".

Assume the user's machine has the Universal CRT installed (i.e. is either Windows 10, or an earlier version including the relevant Windows Update).

Is it **necessary and sufficient** to ship only `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\vcruntime140.dll` alongside my EXE?

Is the situation exactly the same if I use Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Yes, perhaps msvcp140.dll as well for a C++ program.  The UCRT is a system component and maintained by Windows Update.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid running VCRedist on the target system, you have to distribute **ALL dlls** inside the following **two** directories along with your .exe

**First**:

```
(VS2015) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.CRT  
(VS2017) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.15.26706\x86\Microsoft.VC141.CRT
```

**Second**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs\x86
```

Replace 'x86' with 'x64' in directories when compiling a 64-bit app.

Answer (score -3):

You probably want to link your dependencies in statically.

The steps to achieve this in Visual Studio are:

1. Open `Project Properties`
2. Select `C/C++`
3. Select `Code Generation`
4. For `Runtime Library`, select `Multi-threaded (/MT)`

This will work on all recent versions of Visual Studio. The resulting EXE should be standalone.

Comment: The question was "Which DLL(s) must I ship alongside my EXE to use the Windows 10 Universal CRT?"